# how do I pass all these function using only one context

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, reactjs

I have these all context created, but now I want to make it optimized. How do I pass all the created functions using only one context provider.
I have three functions to handle the cart options

1. handleAddProduct
2. handleRemoveProduct
3. handleCartClearance

I've created context for each function but now I want all the functions to be wraped in a single  context provider.

and also need some optimizations for my all three functions because they are taking long to perform the action.

```
import './App.css';
import data from './component/back/Data/data'
import Header from './component/front/Header/Header';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Routiis from './component/front/Routiis/Routiis'
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const AddProduct = createContext();
const RemoveProduct = createContext();
const EmptyCart = createContext();

const App = () => {
  const { productItems } = data;
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

  // function for adding the product...............................................................................................

  const handleAddProduct = (product) => {
    const ProductExist = cartItems.find((item) => item.id === product.id)
    if (ProductExist) {
      setCartItems
          (cartItems.map((item) => item.id === product.id ?
        { ...ProductExist, quantity: ProductExist.quantity + 1 } : item))
    }
    else {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...product, quantity: 1 }])
    }
    
  }

  // function for removing the product..............................................................................................

  const handleRemoveProduct = (product) => {
    const ProductExist = cartItems.find((item) => item.id === product.id)
    if (ProductExist.quantity === 1) {
      setCartItems(cartItems.filter((item) => item.id !== product.id))
    }
    else {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((item) => item.id === product.id ? { ...ProductExist, quantity: ProductExist.quantity - 1 } : item,)
      )
    }
  }

  // function for clearing the cart...................................................................................................

  const handleCartClearance = () => {
    setCartItems([]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='site-bg'>

        <AddProduct.Provider value={handleAddProduct}>
          <RemoveProduct.Provider value={handleRemoveProduct}>
            <EmptyCart.Provider value={handleCartClearance}>
              <Router>
                <Header cartItems={cartItems} />
                <Routiis productItems={productItems} cartItems={cartItems} />
              </Router>
            </EmptyCart.Provider>
          </RemoveProduct.Provider>
        </AddProduct.Provider>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
export { AddProduct, RemoveProduct, EmptyCart }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Provider component accepts a value prop to be passed to consuming components that are descendants of this Provider. you could provide it with an object that carries the properties of the functions. and hence you only need to consume the `Product`

this answers your question

```
 <>
      <div className="site-bg">
        <Product.Provider
          value={{
            handleAddProduct: handleAddProduct,
            handleRemoveProduct: handleRemoveProduct,
            handleCartClearance: handleCartClearance,
          }}
        >
          <Router>
            <Header cartItems={cartItems} />
            <Routiis productItems={productItems} cartItems={cartItems} />
          </Router>
        </Product.Provider>
      </div>
    </>
```

Take a quick look at the official React [context](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api) docs, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is very easy. instead of passing one parameter as value pass it as object as below

```
<AddProduct.Provider value={{handleAddProduct:handleAddProduct,handleRemoveProduct:handleRemoveProduct}}>
</AddProduct.Provider>
```

like this and in your code where you want to use these function just do like this

```
const { handleRemoveProduct,handleAddProduct } = useContext(AddProduct);
```